# Getting a collection of objects

Tags: c#, oop

Say I have a class tree.  If I want to write a function GetTrees() that returns a collection of multiple tree objects where does that function belong?  It doesn't seem to fit in the tree class as I would have to instantiate a tree to get trees?  Do I create a class called Trees (plural) for this sole purpose?

Comment: Are the returned tree objects newly created or do they already exist?

Comment: Where is the collection of tree objects?  It should be implemented in that location, OR a static method should be made that can generate said trees for the returned collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you're using the function for. You may want to make it a static method of the `Tree` class, but more likely you'll want to put it in some kind of data-providing class

Answer (score 3):

Presumably the function "GetTrees" would be on a class that contains (the technical word would be "composes" if the lifetimes are linked, or "aggregates" if they are not) the collection of tree objects.

It certainly does not belong on the tree object itself, since one instance probably shouldn't know about the others. Creating a new class would work, but probably isn't necessary.

In other words, if you have a class "MyStoreClass":

```
public class MyStoreClass
{
   List<Tree> trees;

   public List<Tree> GetTrees
   {
      return trees;
   }
}
```

But it really does belong on whoever owns the list.